# Porting windows application to linux

Tags: linux, porting, freepascal

I have an application which I need to port on Linux. I was thinking to use Free Pascal the problem is the application uses Windows API's to perform tasks such as serial port communication etc... Is there a msdn for linux users or a book covering how linux works internaly if there are apis.

I am very confused.

Comment: you did not specify, was the code originally written in turbo pascal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert Love has a book on Linux Systems Programming - that will cover this area and Love's books are generally good, so it is worth looking at.

It's not entirely clear from your question, but if your concern is that there are specific calls to hardware controlling functions in your Windows application that make it difficult to port I would suggest that is a misplaced fear. Both Windows and Linux operate on the principle that the application level programmer should be kept away from the hardware and that all that should be handled by the operating system kernel and only be accessible to applications via system calls. As the kernels of different operating systems face similar demands from users/applications, they tend to have system calls that do the same sorts of things. It is necessary to match the system calls to one another but I can see no reason why that should be impossible.

What may be more troublesome is that your Windows application may rely heavily on the Windows executive's windowing code/API. Again finding analogues for your code is not impossible but is likely to be a bit more complex e.g. in Linux this stuff is generally not handled in the kernel at all (unlike Windows).

But then again, your code may be written against a portable toolkit/library like Qt which would make things a lot easier.

Good luck in any case.

Comment: I don't see how Qt helps with serial programming. Lazarus/Freepascal can use QT automatically for VCL apps even.

Comment: I didn't say it helped with serial programming. I said it might help with windowing code. This application presumably presents some results to the user.

Comment: If it is an Delphi app, it uses VCL. The Lazarus/FPC equivalent is compatible and renders on LInux  with either GTK2 (or -3 but that is beta) or QT. Anyway, Delphi and Lazarus are component based systems, and there are components for various things that already abstract over Windows/Linux. Better use them as much as possible. (and the advantage is that you can introduce them on Windows first, make sure they work, and only then port)

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's sad to say but if your code in very Windows-dependend (not VCL depended!) then probably it'll be faster to write the application from the begining rather then porting it.

But if it's only serial port matter then give a try to multiplatform SynaSer library, find it here: http://synapse.ararat.cz.

hope this help :)

Comment: And you could use portable toolkit libraries (like Gtk or Qt); this would help coding a Linux application easy to port to MacOSX and to Windows.

Comment: Well, pure VCL is fine - you can use your application with Lazaru's LCL in many flavours of systems with virtually no coding needed, just import Delphi project into Lazarus :) There is also the Code Ocean project which is Lazarus plus a lot of components and libraries ported (including Turbo Power and so on).

Comment: By the way - there are rumors on the net, that Delphi XE3 (or XE4) will have native Linux compiler - and at least FireMonkey ported to it. However status of the VCL is highly unclear mostly due to the Windowish depediences.

Comment: OP should modify his application to use synapse in windows, and once he has it working he should convert project to Lazarus.

Answer (score 1):

If the program contains GUI code you must use linux libraries like GTK/XLIB in order to create windows, forms, buttons, etc...

Windows specific functions (like EnterCriticalSection, WaitForSingleObject or _beginthreadex) must be replaced with equivalent linux api functions (a nice tutorial can be found here: 
"www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-MigratingWin32toLinux.html") or you can use libraries such as [w2lpl](http://www.adontec.com/windows-to-linux-port-library.htm) or [wine](http://www.winehq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

A useful library for this kind of problems i've found at http://www.adontec.com/windows-to-linux-port-library.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've had great experiences just using WINE. (https://www.winehq.org/)
You don't really port your app at all. You just make sure it doesnt violate some of the basc constraints of WINE and just run it as is. WINE (though is says it is not) is an emulator of the windows API's and will just do the translation for you. It's pretty complete in its coverage of the API's.